# How to detect opened sockets in Windows?

Tags: windows, sockets

In Windows XP (SP2 if necessary), is there any way to detect, from a userspace application, that a TCP/UDP socket (from *any* process) has opened?  I know of the `GetExtendedTcpTable()` and `GetExtendedUdpTable()` functions, but they only detect *currently* opened sockets.  Some sockets close immediately after they're opened that the only way I'd be able to detect their existence is by being notified when they open.

If no such a mechanism exists in userspace, I'm willing to go into kernel space to get this functionality.  Are there any documented/undocumented features that could do this?

Comment: Windows includes the executable command `netstat.exe` that shows the current open and listening connections... you might be able to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need to write a WinSock LSP or SPI driver in order to detect that without having to hook every running process directly.